# CAN bus load limitations

Tags: can, bus

I have to send periodic frames with high frequency on a CAN bus. When I do that, the bus load becomes more than 60%, which causes delay with the received frames.

- Is there a problem when using higher bus load?
- Is there any fix for this delay?
- How can I determine the maximum bus load that I can use for low reception delay?

Comment: Bus load is measured as (Number of CAN frames per second/Max possible CAN frames per second for the baud rate). When you are sending frames at high frequency, your node is causing it. It depends on your CAN network how high bus load is tolerable.

Answer (score 2):

CAN bus can only carry one message at a time.

Even when a collision occurs, the arbitration protocol guarantees that the higher-priority message succeeds.

Therefore, as long as the bus bandwidth is not over-subscribed, there will be a fixed upper bound on the delivery delay of any message.

If that bound is higher than what your system can tolerate, then you need to redesign your system.

If you want a more specific answer, then you'll have to provide more details about your system.